# Removing Non-numeric cells from a column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge dataset in Excel with numeric and non-numeric data.
For further analysis i have to exclude all the numeric data.
An idea i had was to create a new column and divide all these cells by 1 and to use only the data with errors.
However, are there any other possible ways to do so?

Best regards and thanks in advance

Comment: `ISNUMBER` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
Sub Macro()

Dim data As Range
Dim Cel As Range

Set data = Range("[Put here the range of your datas]")

    For Each Cel In data
        If IsNumeric(Cel.Value) Then
            Cel.Value = ""
        End If
    Next Cel
    
End Sub
```